# difference between button and div

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Please give me the clarification and differences between button and div ..both in html and jquery.

My problem is I'm using a jquery datepicker. It's opening and closing for a button and not working while I'm trying to work with  div.

```
//working fine
$('#button').datepick();

//not working 
$('#mydiv').datepick();
```

I need a fast solution and very thankful to you if given me a solution.

Comment: somebody given me the down vote for my Question .may i know the mistake of mine ??

Comment: and I up-voted it,  again, there is nothing called a silly question, we all were beginners and didn't know what we know now by anything else ASKING and keep on ASKING AGAIN :).

Comment: thankyou so much for your support  @Mohammed

Comment: welcome @suresh, this site is founded to let us help each other, not to down-vote our questions. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery when you use the hash symbol (`#`), you are referencing the ID of the object, not getting it by type.

If this works:

```
$('#button').datepick();
```

Then you have either:

```
<div id="button"></div>
```

or

```
<input type="button" id="button">
```

You can use which ever one you want. It would probably help to look some more at the jQuery documentation on [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Maybe the example code from the [datepicker](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) plugin will help clarify.

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div type="text" id="datepicker"></div>
```

The ID of the div is `datepicker`, therefore the selector you are passing to the datepicker is `#datepicker`. It could be:

```
<input id="red" type="text">
```

and you would use:

```
$('#red').datepicker();
```

Essentially you are using a selector (in this case ID) to get the object (div or input) that you want to pass to the datepicker API. It in turn does the processing for you using the object you passed it.

Comment: not selecting things man.I want to just know why a date picker  working fine for buttons and input fields .why not its working for div's??